# Prove that $2^{58}+1$ can be written as a product of 3 positive integers, each greater than 1.

Tags: factoring

I first attempted to factor it using SFFT, but I got 3 terms left over that wasn't a product. Am I headed in the right direction, or is the correct answer using a completely different method?

Comment: Is that supposed to be $2^{58}$?

Comment: It had better be, because $2^5\cdot 8+1$ is prime.

Comment: $4 \equiv -1 \pmod{5} \Rightarrow 4^{29} \equiv (-1)^{29} \equiv -1 \pmod{5}$ and you have the 1st factor

Comment: Brute force yields $2^{58}+1=5\times 107367629\times 536903681$, but I'm assuming you're looking for a better method than brute force.

Comment: According to Wolfram Alpha, the factorization is $5pq$ where $p$ and $q$ are two nine-digit prime numbers. I doubt that this is a "fair" problem, where did it come from?

Comment: Also $2^{58}+1=4^{29}+1=(4+1)(4^{28}-4^{27}+4^{26}-4^{25}+4^{24}-...+4^{2}-4^{1}+1)$ ... might be handy

Comment: @Riley - *brute force*? What do you mean by that? Or does checking things on Wolfram count as "brute force"?

Comment: @mathguy I entered it into Wolfram Alpha and the step-by-step solution only showed brute force. Specifically, I mean checking divisibility with every prime up to $\sqrt {\frac{1}{5}(2^{58}+1)}$

Comment: @Riley - you got my meaning. If you check things up on Wolfram, say so - don't pretend you used "brute force."

Comment: @mathguy I don't think that's an important distinction to make because either method ultimately does the same thing. But I apologize if that came across as being dishonest.

Comment: @Riley I think it is not dishonest to use the term "brute force" to include using software, especially for large computation.  I don't understand why mathguy makes an issue out of it.

Comment: No one would interpret that to mean that he checked every triple less than $2^{58}-1$ by hand. Using a computer *is* the brute force method; take your condescension elsewhere please.

Comment: I think brute force is the wrong way to do this, as I would rather not check every single divisor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is this paper on [Cyclotomic and Aurifeuillian polynomials](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.121.3592&rep=rep1&type=pdf) with a section dedicated to the problem of finding factors of large numbers. So
$$2^{58}+1=4^{29}+1=(4+1)\cdot(4^{28}-4^{27}+4^{26}-4^{25}+4^{24}-...+4^{2}-4^{1}+1)$$
$5$ is one factor. Now applying Aurifeuillian factorisation
$$2^{58}+1=2^2\cdot (2^{14})^4+1=\left(2\cdot (2^{14})^2\right)^2+1=\left(2\cdot 2^{28}\right)^2+2\cdot \left(2\cdot 2^{28}\right) +1-2\cdot 2\cdot 2^{28}=\\
\left(2\cdot 2^{28}+1\right)^2-\left(2^{15}\right)^2=\left(2\cdot 2^{28}+1-2^{15}\right)\cdot \left(2\cdot 2^{28}+1+2^{15}\right)=\\
\left(2^{29}+1-2^{15}\right)\cdot \left(2^{29}+1+2^{15}\right)$$
So we found two more factors $2^{29}+1-2^{15}$ and $2^{29}+1+2^{15}$ both clearly larger than $5$. From [Euclid lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid%27s_lemma), $5$ (which is a prime) will divide one of them, thus, there will be (at least) 3 factors.